# WPF Databinding to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm having issues with databinding to the combobox. Other bindings work fine. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

```
 class Bank
    {
        public string bankcode{get; set;}
        public string bankname { get; set; }    
        public ObservableCollection <BankBranch> branches;

    }
    class BankBranch
    {
        public string branchcode { get; set; }
        public string branchname { get; set; }
    }

            Bank b = new Bank{
                bankcode="1",
                bankname="Bank1",
                branches = new ObservableCollection<BankBranch>(){
                    new BankBranch(){branchcode="11", branchname="Location1"},
                    new BankBranch(){branchcode="11", branchname="Location12"}
                },

            };
            bankpanel.DataContext = b;


<StackPanel x:Name="bankpanel">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock >Bank Code</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding bankcode}" Width="100"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock >Bank Name</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding bankname}" Width="100"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock >Bank Branches</TextBlock>

            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding branches}" DisplayMemberPath="branchname" 
 SelectedValuePath="branchname" 
 Width="100">

            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: how looks `Bank` and `BankBranch` classes?

Comment: Simple classes only those properties in the initializer are in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should binding to properties not to fields.

In your case `branches` is declared as field.

Try following code:

```
class Bank
{
    public string bankcode { get; set; }
    public string bankname { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<BankBranch> branches { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Good point !!! Don't know why I skimmed over it

Answer (score 2):

Make `branches` a property. It is currently a field. All bindings must be through properties.